# CSS content before block with padding

Tags: html, css, less

Is it possible/how do I:

Remove the padding when using a CSS content/before selector/property?

E.g. given the follow code, how can I make the bottom paragraph look like the top on (with no white space between the `content:before`) but retain the padding on the paragraph.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/569Ed/2/

HTML5:

```
<div class="no-padding">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="padding">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
p {
    outline: 3px solid #fbb;
    outline-top: 2px solid #fbb;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
p:before {
    content: 'Paragraph';
    border: 1px solid #fbb;
    background-color: #fbb;
    display: block;
}

.padding p {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

*(this is only for the lastest and greatest browsers only, so HTML5 and CSS3/LESS is preferred)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think you can do it this way,

code : http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/569Ed/4/

```
p {
    outline: 3px solid #fbb;
    outline-top: 2px solid #fbb;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.padding p {
    padding: 10px;
}
p:before {
    content: 'Paragraph';
    border: 1px solid #fbb;
    background-color: #fbb;
    display: block;
}
.padding p:before {
    margin:-10px -10px 0 -10px;
}
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: Yea that works, when you add `margin:-10px -10px 10px -10px;` to get the top padding. Thanks.